# Redirect all https requests to http except for checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, https, http-request

I want to redirect all https requests to http on frontend except for checkout. I am using nginx as my web service. Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `System > Config > Web` and set your secure and unsecure url with https and http respectively.

Then set `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` to `No`.

[image]

**Note:**

I would still recommend using https all over the site for security purpose. At least you should use https in admin: `Use Secure URLs in Admin` to `Yes`.

Comment: How do I change that for checkout?

Comment: It will handle automatically.