# Force HTTP on all URLs except what required like checkout, admin

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

We are using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 with Nginx, what we need is to always make sure and force that pages are served HTTP(non-ssl) and only checkout, admin, account and others which required HTTPS(ssl) should work with SSL, otherwise for any other page like frontend or other URL's even if someone deliberately types in https:// it should be forced to http://

We have following settings in Magento backend,

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base URL =
>   http://www.example.com/
>
> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Secure -> Base URL =
>   https://www.example.com/ Use Secure URLs in Frontend = Yes Use Secure
>   URLs in Admin = Yes

With this setting, everything is working fine like checkout and other secure pages are going to forcibly SSL but pages like homepage and other are browseable by both HTTP & HTTPS.

We tried to follow this [Redirect all https requests to http except for checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126293/redirect-all-https-requests-to-http-except-for-checkout) making our

> Use Secure URLs in Frontend = No

But even then if someone types in https://www.example.com/ he/she is not redirected to non-ssl.

I have also tried some settings to do via Nginx but that most of the times causing redirect loop as I am discussing here without much luck https://serverfault.com/questions/814563/redirecting-all-traffic-to-http-except-one-url/814597

Is there any way we can achieve it with just admin panel, or may be combination of both admin and nginx...?

Answer (score 1):

even if you open other pages with **https://** they will be loaded with error, because magento static files and media all have base url with **http://**

in real life situation you can not load https:// if base url configured as http://

but better solution is to use **https://** for unsecure and secure base url configuration.

more secure site and favored by google.

Comment: I know about this, but this is the core requirement for some genuine reason.

Comment: there is no such reason that forces you to make your site less secure. use https for all pages.